# Pass object in directive attribute -Serialised & isolated issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I would like to send a *simple object* from the controller to a *simple directive*...

Here's a part of the object (**Controller**):

```
        var SQLWizard = function(){
            this.steps = {
                query: {
                    title: _('Query'),
                    badge: '2',
                    value: null,
                    onValidation: function () {
                        console.log('query step over');
                    }
                },
                //other properties
            };
            this.currentStep = 1;
        };
        $scope.sqlWizard = new SQLWizard();
```

The **html**:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime"  accordion-wizard="{{sqlWizard}}">
```

> accordion is an [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.3/) element from bootstrap

(The simple) **directive**:

```
app.directive('accordionWizard',function (){
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
             //some stuff here
            }
       }
    });
```

As you can see nothing special there, but I can't understand two things:

1. When catching the object in the directive, I see my object has been serialised and the defined function (onValidation) disappeared!! Why?
2. Why does I can't get all the $scope variable (defined in the controller) into my directive, since the directive doesn't use an isolated scope)?

Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the serialised data is because of the`{{}}`. This will stringify the data to the directive's scope.
2. The isolated scope is related to the first reason, since I've passed my data as a string so I won't be able to modify it (only a copy of it). Then I implicitly tell the directive that my scope is isolated